# rails 3 undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, undefined, update-attributes

Im new to Ruby and rails. Im doing a form which updates :owner value in Hardware database. in using custom views name transfer.html.erb. my form code are display bellow.

```
<%= form_for @hardware, :url => do_transfer_path do |f| %>
```

this is my custom controller in hardwares_tranfers_controller.rb

```
def transfer
  @hardware = Hardware.find(params[:id])
   if current_user.user_lvl == 0
   @users = User.order(:user_lvl)
   else
   @users = User.where(:refer => current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @hardwares }
   end
  end
end


def do_transfer
#    transfer_user = User.where(:id => @hardware.owner).email
#      TransferLog.create([:user_id => current_user.id, :hardware_id => @hardware.id])
  if @hardware.update_attributes(params[:hardware])
    format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "Hardware was successfully transfer"}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @hardware.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

and the error I get is
    NoMethodError in HardwaresTransfersController#do_transfer
    undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass
Aplication Traces
    app/controllers/hardwares_transfers_controller.rb:23:in`do_transfer'

Parameter

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vkwKyuS4eviRN1ogrpOcGh1Y5OBNX0wiBzpV8taNkq0=",
 "hardware"=>{"owner"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Transfer Hardware"}
```

my routes.rb

```
match "hardwares_transfers/" => "hardwares_transfers#do_transfer" , :as => :do_transfer
get "hardwares_transfers/:id/transfer" => "hardwares_transfers#transfer", :as => :transfer_hardwares
```

rake routes>

```
       do_transfer        /hardwares_transfers(.:format)              hardwares_transfers#do_transfer
transfer_hardwares GET    /hardwares_transfers/:id/transfer(.:format) hardwares_transfers#transfer
         hardwares GET    /hardwares(.:format)                        hardwares#index
                   POST   /hardwares(.:format)                        hardwares#create
      new_hardware GET    /hardwares/new(.:format)                    hardwares#new
     edit_hardware GET    /hardwares/:id/edit(.:format)               hardwares#edit
          hardware GET    /hardwares/:id(.:format)                    hardwares#show
                   PUT    /hardwares/:id(.:format)                    hardwares#update
                   DELETE /hardwares/:id(.:format)                    hardwares#destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
def do_transfer
  @hardware = Hardware.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

I'll also take this opportunity to point out that you could probably frame this in a more [REST](http://www.sitepoint.com/restful-rails-part-i/)-ful manner

Comment: ok... when i add that lines it shows this error

ArgumentError in HardwaresController#do_transfer
too few arguments

Answer (score 0):

find hardware item:

```
def do_transfer
  @hardware = Hardware.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

and change route.rb:

```
match "hardwares_transfers/:id" => "hardwares_transfers#do_transfer" , :as => :do_transfer
```

Comment: not working... getting ArgumentError in HardwaresController#do_transfer = too few arguments

Answer (score -1):

The error is `NoMethodError in HardwaresTransfersController#do_transfer`
undefined method update_attributes' for nil:NilClass.

As the error says, that Rails is trying to call update_attributes on nil:NilClass, which implies that your `@hardware` object is nil.
So, you should initialize it by

```
@hardware = Hardware.find(params[:id])
```

You should always look at the error and give it a thought as to why this error is there, it'll help you in learning better.